# Hot to get data from wearable

Tags: android

I don't know how to get those data from smartwatch to my android smartphone. Anyone ever develop apps like this? please help me or you can tell me the reference for me to develop this apps. Please help, Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take reference of the application [SensorDashboard](https://github.com/pocmo/SensorDashboard).
I found it very useful to understand and implement sensor related operations on smart-watch and get it on phone ultimately.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [this Sony Smartwatch link](https://developer.sony.com/develop/wearables/develop-android-wear-apps-for-smartwatch-3/) or the [link for developing apps for Android Wearables](https://developer.android.com/training/building-wearables.html)? If you're really in Indonesia as your profile says you could [look here](https://plus.google.com/communities/106708124212983342256) too.